# Custom image/file folder in the “app” folder that also appear also in iOS emulator in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

For some uncontrolled reason (JSON feed has HTML integrated), I have to have a custom folder with images and files in my app folder apart from /images/ folder.

The problem: Although it shows in the browser, it is not imported to iOS build when I build the project. Is there a way I can have it detected too?

I am using Ionic.

### UPDATE

Neither custom CSS or nor custom Image folder is detectable.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried moving you custom folder to the www-directory? It should get copied to your device...

Comment: Everytime I build it, it erases itself.

Comment: oh wait, let me try that. I thought you mentioned platforms/ios www folder.

Comment: yes, it does clear itself, so unfortunately not working